# How to draw a Graphics ? - xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a graphic in the middle of my layout, which can be restricted in a Linearlayout. Example => [Print App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUi5m.png) This is my application and the graphic has to be in the white area written "Diagram".

The graphic only needs lines and bezier curves.

in fact I do not know if it has a specific object where I can draw.
with lines (x1, y1, x2, y2).

```
public class MyView : View
{
    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);
        Paint green = new Paint {
            AntiAlias = true,
            Color = Color.Rgb(0x99, 0xcc, 0),
        };
        green.SetStyle(Paint.Style.FillAndStroke);

        Paint red = new Paint {
            AntiAlias = true,
            Color = Color.Rgb(0xff, 0x44, 0x44)
        };
        red.SetStyle(Paint.Style.FillAndStroke);

        float middle = canvas.Width * 0.25f;
        canvas.DrawPaint(red);
        canvas.DrawRect(0, 0, middle, canvas.Height, green);
    }
}
```

**How do I draw this in a specific place in my layout?**

Comment: Welcome to SO!  The example is great because it shows what you are trying to accomplish.  For the community to offer helpful suggestions, please show what you have already tried, i.e. some code and then ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I draw this in a specific place in my layout?

After you've complete your draw view `MyView`, you can place it in your layout in xml for example like this:

```
<YOURNAMESPACE.MyView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/myview" />
```

In this case, it can be used like normal UI components in the layout, means you can use `Margin`, `Gravity` and such layout parameters to certain the location where it should be placed.

If you want to implement it in the code behind, you can use [LayoutParams](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.ViewGroup+LayoutParams/). Specific layout code depends on which parent view are you using.

Basically it means, you can draw the view use `Paint` in the subclass of `View` and place it like a UI components in your layout.